# @gmail SQLite Error Android Email ID Key

Tags: android, sql

This is my part of code:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONV
                + " WHERE " + KEY_EMAILID + " = " + user_emailid;
```

While trying to query using:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

I'm getting:

> SQLite Error Code 1 for @gmail

Answer (score 0):

Try like this .. appending `'`. It might solve ur problem

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONV
            + " WHERE " + KEY_EMAILID + " = '" + user_emailid +"'";
```